# shell script convert dec to hex

Tags: shell, hex

Guys am writing a shell script .Here i want to convert a decimal digit to 2 digit hexadecimal value for example if i give 9 it must giv as 09 . 
i have done

`for i in {0..255}; do 
hexa=$(echo "obase=16;$i" | bc)
done` 

but for the first 10 vlaues it returns a single digit hexa value
now how am supposed to convert this

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use printf:

```
$ printf "%02x\n" 12
0c
```

See `man bash` or the manual of your shell of choice.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "enter any number"
read num
i=2
while [ $i -lt $num ]
do
p=`expr $num % $ i`
if [ $p -eq 0 ]
then 
echo "$num is not prime number"
echo "since $num is divisible of $i"
exit
fi
i=`expr $i + 1`
echo "$num is prime number"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in {0..255}; do 
  printf "%X\n" $i
done
```

Comment: Fails akhil's "if i give 9 it must giv as 09"